# Modifying LM334 reference schematic to 100uA/500mV

Tags: current-source, voltage-reference

[image]I'm trying to understand how to modify the circuit below to provide a 100uA constant current drain and 500mV Vds for an ISFET.

Based on the help so far, this is the schematic I've come up with:
[image]

Comment: I get more like 1.1V based on the 10uA current source, 60K resistor and diode @ If = 10mA, 68mV sense voltage. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you want a 0.5V reference that is *capable* of 100uA and must it be low power? And what is your supply voltage? You can't specify both the current and the voltage - at least one will depend on the load. Whatever it is you're trying to do, I don't think modifying this thing is the right way to go about it.

Comment: I need a 100uA current source at ~500mV. Input voltage would be a coin cell so ~3.2 -> 2.2vdc.

Oh, and "hi" Spehro :)

Comment: Hi! Do you mean a 100uA current source with 500mV of compliance? IOW, 100uA into a short , 100uA into 5K and probably less if the load gets much over 5K?

Comment: I've edited the question now that I have more of a clue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, R1 * I1 determines Vds and I2 independently determines your bias current by changing Vgs.

Looking at the I1 current source - its purpose is to create a voltage 500mV above Vout. One easy way to do that is to use an LMV431 1.24V reference hung off the op-amp output and divide the 1.24V down to 500mV. The LMV431 needs at least 80uA to regulate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQdwq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will work up to about 2.7V Vout with a 3.1V supply before the reference runs out of regulation room.

Comment: I like this so far :)

And add the LM334 as L2?

And the Vout would still be tapped underneath C1?

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question to be more specific and put my learnings into a new schematic for heckling^d^d^d^d^danalysis :)

Comment: That may well work, especially if the bias current stability with temperature isn't critical.

Comment: I know how to temperature compensate the LM334 and the ISFET has a temperature diode too.

The ref on the TLV431 is left floating?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Okay- the compliance voltage (minimum voltage for regulation) will likely determine your lower end output range, so you might want to make sure that it's low enough, in the absence of a negative rail.